# order columns by their value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've got a table A with 3 columns that contains the same data, for exemple:

```
TABLE A
KEY  COL1  COL2  COL3
1    A     B     C
2    B     C     null
3    A     null  null
4    D     E     F
5    null  C     B
6    B     C     A
7    D     E     F
```

As a result I expect the distinct values of this table and the order doesn't matter. So key 1 and 6 are the same and 2 and 5 also and 4 and 7. The rest is different.

Ofcourse, I can't use a distinct in my select that will only filter 4 and 7.

I could use a very complex case statement, or a select in a select with an order by. But this needs to be used in a conversion, so performance is an issue here.
Does anyone have a good performant way to do this?

The result I expect

```
COL1  COL2  COL3
A     B     C
B     C     null
A     null  null
D     E     F
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Re-design to get the best performance. For example make sure c1 < c2 < c3 when you store data.

Comment: I can't change the data when it is stored. It is data I get from someone else to convert to a new datamodel. So I need to use the data as it is.

Comment: Can the column values be duplicated?

Comment: there can't be duplicates, only 2 null values like in key = 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can have many columns then you can `UNPIVOT` then order the values and then `PIVOT` and take the `DISTINCT` rows:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( KEY, COL1, COL2, COL3 ) AS
SELECT 1,    'A',     'B',     'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    'B',     'C',     null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    'A',     null,    null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    'D',     'E',     'F'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    null,    'C',     'B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,    'B',     'C',     'A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,    'D',     'E',     'F'  FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM   (
  SELECT key,
         value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY key ORDER BY value ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT ( value FOR name IN ( COL1, COL2, COL3 ) ) u
)
PIVOT ( MAX( value ) FOR rn IN (
  1 AS COL1,
  2 AS COL2,
  3 AS COL3
) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> COL1 | COL2 | COL3
> :--- | :--- | :---
> A    | B    | C   
> B    | C    | null
> D    | E    | F   
> A    | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=28693424a369707ad288f159f7dd72e3)*

Answer (score 0):

The complicated `case` expression is going to have the best performance.  But the simplest method is going to be conditional aggregation:

```
select key,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col3
from (select key,col,
             row_number() over (partition by key order by col asc) as seqnum
      from ((select key, col1 as col from t) union all
            (select key, col2 as col from t) union all
            (select key, col3 as col from t)
           ) kc
      where col is not null
     ) kc
group by key;
```

Comment: This gives `(KEY,COL1,COL2,COL3) -> (1,C,B,A),(2,C,B,null),(3,A,null,null),(4,F,E,D),(5,C,B),(6,C,B,A),(7,F,E,D)` as result.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . They were ordered highest first.  I changed the answer to be lowest first.